# Count odd digits of a number with recursive method

Tags: java

I tried to write a simple java program which counts how many odd digits there are inside a number (for example, for input "123" the program should return 2). The program instead returns all the digits of the given number. Any idea?

```
import java.util.*;

//Counts the number of odd digits in an int using recursion
public class OddCount{
    public static void main(String[]args){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Digit a positive int number: ");
        int n = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("The number of odd digits is " + oddDigitCounter(n));
    }


    public static int oddDigitCounter(int number) {
        int result = 0;
        if(number<=10){
            if(number%2==0)
                result = 0;
            else
                result++;
        }
        else{
            if(number%10!=0){
                if((number%10)/2!=0)
                    result = 1 + oddDigitCounter(number/10);
                else
                    result = 0 + oddDigitCounter(number/10);
            }
            else{
                result = 0 + oddDigitCounter(number/10);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's an awful lot of unnecessary conditions.

Comment: Isn't your approach a bit out of the scope? Aren't you looking for every single digit regardless on how they are assembled?

Comment: Divide problem into independent 1. get digital form of a number (i.e. format number to String or char[]) 2. Do logic with digits. Your algorithm is unreadable, unmodifiable, and probably wrong

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a way to write your recursive method without all the unnecessary conditions.

```
public static int oddDigitCounter(int number) {
    if (number==0) {
        return 0;
    }
    return (number&1) + oddDigitCounter(number/10);
}
```

Using `&1` instead of `%2` allows it to work for negative numbers as well as positive ones.<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> `(number&1)` is zero for an even number, and one for an odd number, and works regardless of whether the number is positive or negative. For instance, if `number==-3` then `(number%2)==-1`, but `(number&1)==1`, which is what we want in this case.

Comment: Good that you posted this. Newbies need to look at good code.

Comment: For newbies, an explanation of why `&1` is "similar" than `%2` could be usefull. But I had the same solution without this trick!

Comment: @khelwood, Awesome. I thought my answer was simple. Congratulations

Comment: _bitwise and_ and a division to `int`. Nice. However I don't know why people even like the recursive way ;-) What a pitty isn't there something like `anInteger.ints().filter(Integer::isOdd).count()`... but at least something similar is possible :-)

Comment: What does &1 do compared to mod 2?

Comment: @69420 If `number` is (for instance)`-1` then `number % 2` is `-1`, but `number & 1` is 1, which is what we want in this case.

Comment: Ah I see so what if number is -3, would &1 make it 3? Is it like an absolute value?

Comment: @69420 No, `number&1` is 1 for odd numbers and 0 for even numbers. So `(-3)&1` is 1.

Comment: @khelwood I get it now thanks. (-4)&0 is 0? How would this help if we were to for instance find number of even characters?

Comment: @69420 Yes, `(-4)&0` is zero. That would not help you find the number of even digits; but that would be another question.

Answer (score 0):

Check your code, you are using / instead of % in this if condition:

```
 if((number%10)/2!=0)
```

It should be:

```
if((number%10)%2!=0)
```

Comment: Why `(number%10)%2` rather than just `number%2` ?

Comment: additional note: The only even number that will get 0 as a result when divided by 2 is 0 itself. So in fact the original code did not count all digits, but all digits that aren't 0.

Answer (score 0):

In oddDigitCounter() why don't you simply check digit by digit if it's an even or odd one and echo (store) the result?

Recursive approach: at first call you may pass to the function the entire number and then if the number is 1 digit long let the function do the check and return, otherwhise do the check against the 1st digit and pass the others again to the function itself.

Procedural approach: do a simple loop through the digits and do the checks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following sample:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NumberOfOddDigist {

    private static int count = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Digit a positive int number: ");
        int n = in.nextInt();
        countOdd(n);
        System.out.println("The number of odd digits is " + count);
        in.close();
    }

    public static void countOdd(int number) {

        int remainder = number % 10;
        int quotient = (number - remainder) / 10;

        if (!(remainder % 2 == 0)) {
            count++;
        }

        number = quotient;
        if (number < 10) {
            if (!(number % 2 == 0)) {
                count++;
            }
        } else {
            countOdd(number);
        }
    }

}
```